# Git a better way for leaving WIP branch and start working on a another branch

Tags: java, android, git, version-control, gitlab

I am working on a branch (feature01) and it is still work in progress. Now I have to leave the WIP branch and start working on another feature/bugfix and for that, I have to create a new branch out of my development branch. I usually stash all the changes in feature01 and start working on a new branch. I don't like this solution that much as I can be working on the new branch for a day or so and I have to remember that there is something on the stash. Is there any localized version of stash for each branch or something of that sort so that I can move around between different WIP branches without having to stash a bunch of stuff and keeping track of them manually.

One solution I was thinking of was committing the local changes before checking out to a new branch and then later when the work is done on one of the WIP branch, I can squash some of the commits together with a more meaningful message rather than having a bunch of commits with not so helpful messages.

I would like to know if you guys know better solutions to this problem or if this problem is arising because my git workflow is not correct. I searched for solutions online but most people recommend stashing which I don't like much when the changes stay for a longer time in the stash.

Cheers.
Waqar

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest using a temporary commit :

```
# you have unfinished modifications to save before switching
git commit -am "temp - DO NOT PUSH"
git checkout other-branch
```

Then you can work on the `other-branch`, and when you're done, it's easy to undo the commit on `previous-branch` while keeping its contents

```
git checkout previous-branch
git reset HEAD^
```

---

Of course, it's easier when you have aliases

```
git config --global alias.ct 'commit -am "temp - DO NOT PUSH"'
git config --global alias.rs1 'reset HEAD^'
```

Then just

```
# to save uncommited changes ON the branch
git ct

# to "unravel" a temp commit
git rs1
```

Comment: I will try it and get back to you on it.
I found a link to GitFlow which is basically what everyone does with slight modifications and I think its a good read.
https://datasift.github.io/gitflow/IntroducingGitFlow.html
https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

Comment: @WaqarRashid I use it on a daily basis myself, since I too am not too fond of `stash` and the mess it can quickly become.

Comment: I use stash when I know I don't need to keep the changes there longer. More than 30 mins and it creates a mess. Your answer was really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @WaqarRashid You're welcome. And it seems we both use the stash basically as a bin/trash :-)

Comment: It would be nicer if you can add more explanation to the aliases as I didn't know their usefulness before your answer. It might be helpful to other people as well and a little knowledge for the curious ones.

Comment: Maybe adding some information from the GitFlow links. It will make it a very complete answer.

Comment: You're right, I'll try to detail a bit later today.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202344/discussion-between-waqar-rashid-and-romainvaleri).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of stashing or doing a temporary commit, another solution is to use the [git worktree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) feature to work in another folder (but still within the same repository).

A blog post on the subject: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/06/26/parallelize-development-git-worktrees/

Comment: While this may look like out of scope to some, I think this is definitely the better answer. Thank you for your insight Philippe!

Answer (score 0):

Git uses commit id's such us `521747298a3790fde1710f3aa2d03b55020575aa`.

This hashcode keeps every changes in your code. if you want to change your branch without commit, its not logical according to git rules. Every changes must be marked with this hashcode. To extend you can choose which commits must be push.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think making temporary commits before checking out would be the best solution as those temporary commits can be squashed together or removed. @RomainValeri answer explains it very nicely I think and has aliases that will make it alot easier.